# Installing v8 on mac: v8: command not found

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, homebrew, v8

I am trying to use v8 on mac and I have tried installing it using homebrew.

When i run:

```
brew install v8
```

I get:

```
Warning: v8 7.3.492.27 is already installed and up-to-date
```

But, when I run v8 command in terminal i get:

```
-bash: v8: command not found
```

And also when I try to install v8js i get the following:

```
configure: error: Please reinstall the v8 distribution
```

Any idea why these issues are happening when it's telling me that I have a version of v8 installed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error but i realised the command has been changed from `v8` to `d8`

Run this command instead

```
d8
```